# Create one array with objects from many arrays with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

This is initial code with one array with 3 arrays inside. And those 3 arrays has objects inside (It can be 1 or multiple)

```
[
    [
        {
            "item1": "text",
            "item2": 1
        },
        {
            "item1": "text",
            "item2": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "item1": "text",
            "item2": 3
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "item1": "text",
            "item2": 4
        },
        {
            "item1": "text",
            "item2": 5
        },
        {
            "item1": "text",
            "item2": 6
        }
    ]
]
```

Expected result

```
[
    {
        "item1": "text",
        "item2": 1
    },
    {
        "item1": "text",
        "item2": 2
    },
    {
        "item1": "text",
        "item2": 3
    },
    ...
]
```

So, as a result I need only 1 array with many objects.

Comment: use array.flat()

Comment: what happens to object with `item2: 3`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Nothing, I've edit text. stackoverflow didn't allow me to post, said "too much code", so I cut som of it. -- flat is perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'lodash' ?

in lodash you have some functions already preset for arrays in javascript or in case typescript.

for example you can use flattenDeep.

you must import lodash into your project and then use it however you like.

By default, the global name for the lodash import used by developers is '_', so if you go to the lodash page you will see all the examples displayed like this.

example of import:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

in your code

```
_.flattenDeep([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]);
// => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if you have problems for import lodash in your proyect you can try this
: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/import-lodash-libraries

for something more custom if you have any other need you can use something native like flat, here you have the documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: array.flat() Wokring great for this case.